Do I need a buck IC to get 3.3 V, or a buck/boost, or an LDO?
The voltage supply of my FPGA and sensors circuit is 3.3 V. If I use a Li-po battery with 3.7 V nominal voltage and 3 V discharge cut-off voltage (the LP-803860 3.7 V, 2000 mAh with PCM), do I need a buck IC to get 3.3 V, or a buck/boost, or an LDO?


do i need a buck IC to get 3.3V or A Buck/Boost or an LDO?

A buck-boost converter is needed to get 3.3 volts out from an input supply range of 3 volts to anything over 3.3 volts. There are plenty available but the fine detail needed for selection is the current consumption of your FPGA/sensors.

Note also that here you can (potentially, subject to other requirements) use a standard inverting buck-boost instead of the slightly more complicated non-inverting buck-boost, too; just define your battery positive as ground, instead of the negative.

the maximum current consumption of the circuit is 600mA , so i suppose that the regulator's output current must be 1A !

What is the standby current of your circuit @NihelKh

There are some intriguing possibilities these days such as single-inductor buck-boost using 4 switches (expensive IC though) and inductorless switched capacitor types.
But the selection and design will depend on the detailed requirements.
